# What differences are there between the Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha anime and manga?

Tags: nanoha

I'm look into reading ViviD and Force, the two sequel manga to the StrikerS manga, and I am wondering: what differences are there between the three anime seasons and the three related manga that could affect the reading of ViviD and Force?

Comment: I'll note that there is now an ongoing Vivid anime.  I have no idea what relation there is between the Vivid manga and anime.

Comment: @zibadawatimmy to my understanding the ViVid anime is an adaptation of the Manga

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing! The aforementioned manga provides minor additional background for fans. This includes:

- Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha MOVIE 1st THE COMICS
- Magical Girl Lyrical Nanoha A's
- Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha StrikerS THE COMICS

The remaining manga continues with an unique story:

- Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha ViVid
- Mahou Shoujo Lyrical Nanoha Force

The former is a carefree spin-off focusing on Vivio (but fun!), while the latter continues Nanoha's story.